# Changing defaultAudience when sharing to a feed using Facebook IOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook

Using the IOS SDK for Facebook (3.1) , I find that once I set up my project, I am unable to change the default audience.

For instance, I set up my test project to publish to "Only Me". It works fine. I am working off of this example, making the change that I start out with audience "Only Me".

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/publish-to-feed-ios-sdk/

Then I arrange to call the following:

```
        [FBSession.activeSession
         reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:
         [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]
         defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 // If permissions granted, publish the story
                 NSLog (@"Here goes nothing");
                 [self publishStory];
             }
         }];
```

which should publish the story to DefaultAudienceFriends. However, it continues to publish to Only Me.

Shouldn't this work? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is the answer I came up with, which addresses my particular need. I change the privacy settings for the app, in Facebook, here:

http://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications

And come to think of it, this makes sense. I, as a user of this app (which I happened to create, but that probably isn't relevant), am specifying the behavior it displays when it posts on my behalf.

So I'm happy, because now I can work on my app, freely test it, without disturbing anybody. And I can change it to post more widely, when I'm ready.

Answer (score 0):

During the authorization flow you set the default audience, in your case "Only Me". Now that your app has permissions trying to reauthorize will likely do nothing, unless you probably logout and back in. What you can try doing instead is passing the audience you want as a part of the post parameter.

So, based on the sample, let's say you wanted "Only Me", you would add:

```
[self.postParams setObject:@"{'value':'SELF'}",
                        forKey:@"privacy"];
```

And if you wanted "Friends", you would use:

```
[self.postParams setObject:@"{'value':'ALL_FRIENDS'}",
                        forKey:@"privacy"];
```

Comment: Well, part of the flow I'm using, again from the example in the IOS SDK documentation, is to logout. But logging out doesn't seem to fully make the session info go away. So I'm not ready to mark your answer as a solution.  But I'll keep beating on it, and post back to this thread, if I come up with something. I'm reluctant to integrate this code into my main App, until I figure this out, in my test App.

Comment: But then again, I see you work at Facebook, so maybe I should give it another go :-)

Comment: So when I logout, I call [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation]; Then I log back in, and my attempt to change the privacy setting again fails. So what I conclude is that closeAndClearTokenInformation doesn't truly clear out the previous session information.

Comment: What about trying to set the privacy parameter. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yeah. Inside my shareButtonAction method, I am now doing        [self.postParams setObject:@"{'value':'ALL_FRIENDS'}" forKey:@"privacy"]; just as you originally suggested. I can't see that it has any effect.

Comment: Do you know if there is a known bug with this? If not, then I'll keep at it until I figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Now I'm wondering if this could be an issue with cookies. I get the same stickiness, in my Simulator, and on my phone, even after removing cookies, though. So that's not real promising. I just can't seem to find a way to clear out old Session data.

Comment: The reason I care about this is I want to integrate this Facebook sharing code into an existing IOS app I have. While I'm testing it, I want to avoid spamming my real-life Facebook friends with all my tests. So I want to share with "only me" during testing, and then turn on sharing with friends, when I go live.

Comment: Not that this answers the original question but if you only care about not spamming your friends, you can do the following: Go to www.facebook.com and find your app privacy settings (https://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=applications) then find your app, tap Edit and change the post privacy settings to Only Me.